# preg_match for tokens with brackets

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to parse a string and get tokens out of it that are defined as `token[content]`. Example:

```
url[javascript:void(0)] onclick[somedata] img[someimage] LinkKey[abcd]
```

I am using `preg_match` for it but the regex is not working the way I want to. Effectively the tokens are either at the beginning of the contents or in the middle. If in the middle they are preceded by a space. The token is some string, followed by a bracket, content and a closing bracket. In the above example I need to get the result url, onclick, img, LinkKey.

I have tried

```
(.*\[.*\])
```

but it doesn't match the tokens correctly

Any pointers are more than appreciated.

Comment: How is token `LinkKey` different from `img` or `onclick` here?

Comment: It is a token on its own that has some content enclosed in brackets after its name i.e. `LinkKey[abcde]`.

Comment: Check @CasimiretHippolyte's answer for clean solution of your task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try this regular expression:

```
([^\[]+\[[^\]]+\])
```

Your problem could be that your regual expression is interpreted greese so that all chars until the last `]` would be consumed. To force non gready you could also try this one:

```
(.*?\[.*?\])
```

If you only want to match elements beginning with url or img you could use this one:

```
((?:url|img)\[[^\]]+\])
```

A short explenation about that `(?:url|img)` that allows only `url` or `img` the `?:` meanes that this group should not been matched.

Comment: Thank you. It was a typo in the question - corrected re: slashes

Comment: The above works in getting the tokens and the content i.e. `img[someimage]`. I was wondering if there is a way to get only the word `url` i.e. the token name?

Comment: If you want only with the prefix url try this: `(url\[[^\]]+\])`

Comment: Maybe I was not clear. The above returns url[xxx], img[yyy[ etc. I want to get only the url and img in the results. Is there a way to get that? Thanks!

Comment: That is the issue though. I don't know all the possible tokens (like url/img/onclick etc. That is what I am trying to find out.

Comment: I see that's a little more complicated. There are some tricks you could use anyway I would prefer to match only the string (first regex) and parse the prefix in a second step. For the second step I would use this: `explode(rtrim($regexGroup, ']', '[')` this will return a simple array with the prefix and the value.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
preg_match_all('~(?<tok>[^[\s]++)\[(?<con>[^]]++)]~', $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

print_r($matches);
```

the position doesn't matter.